# CRS Conversion problem

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, arcgis-10.1, romania

I have two datasets representing the same area in Romania, but in different CRS, A is local, B is WGS 84.

**dataset A with:**

Stereo_70
Authority: Custom

Projection: Double_Stereographic
False_Easting: 500000,0
False_Northing: 500000,0
Longitude_Of_Origin: 25,0
Scale_Factor: 0,99975
Latitude_Of_Origin: 46,0
Linear Unit: Meter (1,0)

Geographic Coordinate System: GCS_Dealul_Piscului_1970
Angular Unit: Degree (0,0174532925199433)
Prime Meridian: Greenwich (0,0)
Datum: D_Dealul_Piscului_1970
  Spheroid: Krasovsky_1940
    Semimajor Axis: 6378245,0
    Semiminor Axis: 6356863,018773047
    Inverse Flattening: 298,3

**and dataset B with:**

WGS 84
WKID: 4326 Authority: EPSG

Angular Unit: degree (0,0174532925199433)
Prime Meridian: Greenwich (0,0)
Datum: WGS_1984
  Spheroid: WGS 84
    Semimajor Axis: 6378137,0
    Semiminor Axis: 6356752,314245179
    Inverse Flattening: 298,257223563

In order to convert B to A, I imported A's CRS to B=> Datasets did not overlap, they are miles away from each other.

Could anyone explain what exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert a feature class with coordinate system B to a feature class with coordinate system B you can use several approaches.

One possibility is to use [Project (Data Management)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/#/Project/00170000007m000000/) . You have to specify a datum transformation in this tool too.

Another way is: Add feature class A to a new data frame. Then add feature class B. Set datum transformation in data frame properties. Now both feature classes should align so that you can work with both feature classes. If you want to create a new feature class: Right click to layer B and export it to a new feature class.

Comment: checked first possibility before; didn't work. tried second: Added feature class A to a new data frame. Then added feature class B. Set datum transformation in data frame properties. feature classes didn't align:(

Comment: When adding data A to ArcMap, ArcMap reads the coordinate system information stored with data A. The data frame use coordinate system A. If you add data B to the same data frame ArcMap will project data B 'on-the-fly' to the coordinate system that is set for the data frame (A). If the proper datum transformation is not specified you will see a misalginment of about 50 to 500 meters. If the coordinate system definition of A or B is incorrect you will see a very large misalginment (up to thousands of kilometers). So I assume: the coordinate system definition of A and/or B is incorrect.

Comment: This is exactly what I was writing now :) I think the coordinate system for B be is defined incorrectly. what do I do in this case?

Comment: Do you know the corret coordinate system for B? Then use the tool Define Projection (Data Management) to overwrite the coordinate system information of B.

Comment: I assume B is WGS 1984. Meanwhile I deleted any.prj file I had for B, gave them from ArcCatalog the WGS 1984 geographic coordinate system-> and then in ArcMap-> Project (with the projection of A). There is still a difference of aprox. 50 m.

Comment: Is the difference of 50 m always in the same direction? Then I suspect a problem with the datum transformation. Have you used the right transformation?

Comment: 1. Hi again, we're talking about a 50 m to the east, but as I looked carefully now, it could be just a matter of bad digitization for databaset B, because on certain sections it overlaps perfectly.  2. I added Bing Aerial Basemap, the difference between the basemap and the two feature classes is 180 m to the east, and around 35 m to the south.

Comment: to 1: I think your original problem is solved: A and B have a misalginment of 0 meters to 50 meteres because of bad digitization. to 2: I suspect that the datum transformation from A to Bing and from B to Bing is not correct. To solve this problem I would start a new question on gis.stackexchange.

Comment: thank you very much for all your replies. It definitely cleared  out the problem. Now I'll start finding solutions to a new one:)